# Full Text Search with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7B7FyU9wW8Y) about Full Text Search in GAE, however I cannot find a way to see sample codes that will show Full Text Search using Datastore Entities as described in the video.

Was the feature of Full Text Search for Datastore Entities actually did exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no full text search on data store entities. Full text search is available as its own service, [See Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/).

Comment: So the video is not true?

Comment: Looking at the first few minutes of the video, I can see the full text search features they talk about belong to the Search Api, not the Datastore. They may be duplicating the entities in the Datastore in Documents for the Search Api, so that search results return the entities' keys on the Datastore.